# Compute $\iiint_G \frac{xyz}{(a^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^3}dxdydz$.

Tags: multiple-integral

How to compute this integral ?
$$\iiint_G \frac{xyz}{(a^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^3}dxdydz$$
where
$$G =\Big\{x^2 + y^2 \le a^2, y^2 + z^2 \le a^2, x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0 \Big\}.$$
I suggest that spherical coordinates can help, but I don't know how to compute it in overall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$I:=\iiint_{G_a} \frac{xyz}{(a^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^3}dxdydz.$$
Cartesian coordinates are fine. $G$ is the intersection of two cylinders in the first octant:
$$G_a =\Big\{0\leq  y \le \min\left(\sqrt{a^2-x^2},\sqrt{a^2-z^2}\right), x \in[0,a], z\in[0,a] \Big\}.$$
Note that the integral is independent with respect to $a$:
letting $X=x/a$, $Y=y/a$ and $Z=z/a$ then
$$I=\iiint_{G_1} \frac{a^3 XYZ}{a^6(1 + X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2)^3}(a^3dXdYdZ)=\iiint_{G_1} \frac{XYZ}{(1 + X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2)^3}dXdYdZ$$
Therefore we may assume that $a=1$.

By symmetry of the integrand with respect to the swapping $z\leftrightarrow x$, we have that
\begin{align}I
&=
2\int_{x=0}^1\int_{z=0}^x\int_{y=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{xyz}{(1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^3}dydzdx\\
&=
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{x=0}^1\int_{z=0}^x\left[\frac{xz}{(1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2}\right]_{y=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dzdx\\
&=
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{x=0}^1\int_{z=0}^x\frac{xz}{(2 + z^2)^2} dzdx
+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x=0}^1\int_{z=0}^x\frac{xz}{(1 + x^2+ z^2)^2} dzdx\\
&=
\frac{1}{4}\int_{x=0}^1\left[\frac{x}{2 + z^2} \right]_{z=0}^x dx
-\frac{1}{4}\int_{x=0}^1\left[\frac{x}{1 +x^2+ z^2} \right]_{z=0}^x dx\\
&=
\frac{1}{4}\int_{x=0}^1\left(\frac{x}{2 + x^2}
-\frac{x}{2}
-\frac{x}{1 + 2x^2}
+\frac{x}{1 + x^2}\right)dx\\
&=
\frac{1}{16}\left[2\ln(2+x^2)-x^2-\ln(1+2x^2)+2\ln(1+x^2)\right]_{x=0}^1\\
&=\frac{\ln(3)-1}{16}.
\end{align}

Comment: @marka_17 Any further doubt?